# How to check if optional function parameter is set

Tags: python, rendering, scripting

I want to append some code to the `bpy.app.handlers.render_post` operator.
But I need to know whether the `bpy.ops.render.render()` operator has been called with the `animation` parameter (/argument?) set to `True` or `False`.

```
import bpy

def mRenderOutput(scene):
    print(getattr(bpy.ops.render.render, "animation"))
    #something like: if bpy.ops.render.render.animation == True: do my code

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.render_post.append(mRenderOutput)   

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.render_post.remove(mRenderOutput)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Unfortunately, this throws:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\morph3us\Desktop\mRenderOutput\mSaveRender001.blend\Text.004",
>   line 4, in mRenderOutput AttributeError: 'BPyOpsSubModOp' object has
>   no attribute 'animation'

So my question:
How can I detect in an if clause inside of "mRenderOutput" whether a still image or an animation has been rendered?

Comment: `bpy.ops.foo.bar` is not an instance of nor the operator class. Have a look at `context.active_operator` or in the window managers operators collection.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I do not fully understand what you are saying, although I have been trying to figure it out for the past 3 hours, but I hope I will eventually get behind it!

Comment: Sorry bum steer the render operator isn't added to wm's operators collection.  Once apon a time could get all operator classes from bpy.types, appears no longer the case.  One way is to look at the other render handlers. More than one render between render init and complete suggests animation. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/62870/15543

Comment: I would like to automatically save still images and rename the output
(e.g. *scene* = scene name, *cam* = cam name, etc.)
There are 3 different cases:
1. Still Image
2. Animation - Output as movie file
3. Animation - Output as image sequence
I couldnt just check the output file type because of case 3.
I couldnt check the timeline length, too, one could also render one still frame from an animation.
Also, first rendering an image sequence and renaming when finished is bad, as they wouldnt be renamed at all if the PC gets stuck somewhere in between.
But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Another is to create your own render operator that  calls the old one.

Comment: Oh and "somewhere between init and complete" could also be the second.